# Convert the y-axis values to Millions in dual axis high charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, datatables

I am using dual-axis highcharts. In the y-axis the values are too big to read. I wold like to convert them to shortcuts like 1K for 1000 and 1.0L for 100000 and 1.0M for 1000000 and 35.8M for 35869982 and 3.5M for 3550977.

This is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3az4x4nu/1/)

```
 $(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['MAR-2014', 'APR-2014', 'MAY-2014', 'JUN-2014',
            'JUL-2014', 'AUG-2014', 'SEP-2014', 'OCT-2014', 'NOV-2014', 'DEC-2014'],
        crosshair: true
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'VOLUME',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'REVENUE',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 120,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Revenue',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [35869982, 26090976, 26595718, 33914250, 25999278, 36579864, 35843674, 28008920, 27718356, 29014230],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' '
        }

    }, {
        name: 'volume',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [3379865, 2373769, 2401815, 3222316, 2459713, 5864469, 5139453, 3341922, 3229963, 3550977],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        }
      }]
    });
   });
```

Here I have rounded up where I want to make changes in the below figure

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make a use of formatter:

```
formatter: function(){
              return this.value/1000000 + "M";
            }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mokshshah/3az4x4nu/5/)

Comment: Hey sorry thats not to percentage. I mst convert into millions by replacing with M

Comment: Then simply `divide value by 1000000`.

Comment: @rjirji, I've updated my ans and fiddle too, you may mark it as answer if it helps.

Comment: This is fine. But look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3az4x4nu/6/ the arrays will be appended dynamically in the same case how can I do the same this here

Comment: It doesn't matter, you need to just change from this `format: '{value} ',` to above formatter.

Comment: How can I get it in tool tip?

Comment: You can use [Highcharts.numberFormat](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat)

Answer (score 3):

To utilize the built in "shortening" functionality you can just remove your `yAxis.label.format`. You have currently set it to `{value}`, which is the default, but manually setting it seems to prevent the metric prefixes from being applied.

Look at [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3az4x4nu/8/), where all I've changed is removing the following line from both of your y-axis labels:

```
format: '{value}'
```

With this automatic shortening the following [metric prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) may be applied:

```
[ "k" , "M" , "G" , "T" , "P" , "E"]
```

You can set your own values with the `lang.numericSymbols` option ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.numericSymbols)).